# Fragment pagination across multiple documents in elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on searching documents with given keyword in elasticsearch.

I have an index mapping like this.

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "term_vector": "yes"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "0"
    }
}
```

The `text` field may contains multiple keyword like following.

```
keyword: "foo"
text: "foo bar baz foo bar foo baz ...long text"
```

I search the documents with the keyword `foo` and get many documents contains the keyword.

```json
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "foo"
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't want to display the whole long text on the page. I want to cut the text and show like this.

```
1. aaa foo bbb
2. aaa foo ccc
3. bbb foo ddd
...
```

The problem is how to make a pagination on this.

1. If I only take the first fragment in each document, what about the fragments behind?
2. If I takes the fragments from one document to other one, the whole page will show the results from only one document and the second page is difficult to solve when the first page crosses multiple documents.

Is there any efficient way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked into [highlighter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) ?

Comment: Yes. But using highlighter also has problems. The `fragment_size` can not cut the text accurately. It usually returns more and less characters when there are chinese simplified characters in the field. So I decide to cut the text by myself. Then I can not get the total fragments number in a document so that I can not make a pagination. Now, I fetch the whole text field and use regular expression to match the first fragment to archive my goal.